# Errors while performing schema compare

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to perform a schema compare using the latest VS 2019 and SSDT tools.
However, two errors appear, which both start with:
`An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type`

If I do the same SQL compare from VS 2017, there are no errors.

The first is:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlDatabaseCredential: Batch Command during reverse engineer failed with Error Code: -2146232060 Line Number: 7 Error Message:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.

...

Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'..          0
```

And the second is:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlErrorMessage: Batch Command during reverse engineer failed with Error Code: -2146232060 Line Number: 15 Error Message:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.

...

Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'.   
Incorrect syntax near 'HINT'..          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  Schema comparison from VS2019 to SQL Server 13.0.x failed. It worked properly with other SQL Server instances (other versions).
I applied all updates on SQL server up to 13.0.5292.0, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Using VS 2017 instead of VS 2019 worked for me, too, but I'll try updating the SQL server.  It's sitting on a local VM, so I haven't updated it in ages.  That'll probably do the trick.